# @supports css calc function

Tags: css, css-calc

Is there a way to use the [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) in [@supports(propertyName, value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)? i mean where `<supports_condition>` is only for the calc function.

```
@supports ( <supports_condition> ) {
    .col-3 {
    width: calc(25% - 20px/4)
    }
    .col-4 {
        width: calc(33.3333333% - 20px/3)
    }
    .col-6 {
        width: calc(50% - 20px/2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Support for [`@supports`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries) is far, far more restricted than [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) because the latter was introduced several years earlier (most notably, IE doesn't support `@supports` at all, whereas it has supported `calc()` since version 9 which came out almost exactly 4 years ago). If you were to use them together, every browser that supports `@supports` would match that rule, and any browser that supports `calc()` but not `@supports` would ignore that rule. In other words, if you were to use them together you'd be *reducing* the number of browsers that can use the `calc()` function by preventing some of them from ever seeing your declarations.

Fortunately, since `calc()` is a value, in lieu of a not-yet-existing `@supports` authors could simply take advantage of the cascade by providing fallback declarations for when `calc()` isn't supported:

```
width: 95px;
width: calc(25% - 20px/4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see if any `calc` condition works in the `@support` condition, and if it does, tell it to do what you actually want. So something like: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cpf93px/)

```
@supports (width: calc(100% - 80em)) {
    div {
        width: calc(100% - 3em);
    }
}
```

See [This line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#Testing_for_the_support_of_a_given_CSS_property_or_a_prefixed_version) for Mozilla's documentation.