# Unnecessary use of calc() in MDN example?

Tags: html, css

I just read up on the CSS function `calc()` in Mozilla's Developer Network.

The first example in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) uses the following CSS code:

```
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(40px);
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And this HTML markup:

```
<div class="banner">This is a banner!</div>
```

Pardon me, if this is an overly trivial question, but is there any reason to use `left: calc(40px)` or is that simply a mistake? Since there is nothing to compute, I'd just put `left: 40px;`.

Comment: MDN is a wiki - perhaps you could fix this :)

Comment: Looking back in the history, [it originally had](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc$revision/1305127) non-`calc` based fallback properties too.  Looks like it dates from then, so the fixed `40px` would match with the actual `calc` property, ie it's either based on percentages or px based calculations depending on what the browser supports.

Comment: To be honest, that whole example is a bit odd. I'd just use `left: 40px;` and `right: 40px;` for the same result.

Comment: I could only imagine that this is in place in order to show that `calc()` can - theoretically - be used like this, even if it has little relevance in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. `calc(40px)` is equivalent to `40px`. It's not clear if the example actually meant to demonstrate exactly that, and if so, why it felt the need to do so, as it's clearly not how `calc()` was intended to be used.

Perhaps it's a way to hide the `left` declaration from older browsers that don't understand `calc()`, since browsers that don't understand it would ignore the `width` declaration, but still apply a `left: 40px` (sans `calc()`) declaration, with adverse effects. But this is just an educated guess on my part. This is exactly the kind of situation `@supports` was created for; however, since [`calc()` pre-dates `@supports` by several years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001096/supports-css-calc-function/29001668#29001668), `@supports` can't be used here, and so the only other option is to take advantage of CSS's [well-defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#unsupported-values) [error-handling rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#illegalvalues).

(In fact, I recently created a CSS hack that makes use of a lone `calc(0s)` expression to [hide rules from older versions of Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575563/conditional-css-rule-targeting-firefox-quantum/47798653#47798653). Ironically, that expression does reside in a `@supports` feature query, as Firefox introduced support for `calc()` with <time> values several years *after* `@supports`.)

Comment: Looking at the comments in the revision linked by @JamesThorpe, I'd guess you're right about the adverse effects of not inerpreting `calc`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `calc()` is intended to be used with expressions, and `40px` is a value, not an expression. Using `calc()` with a value is pointless and wasteful of resources. I have no idea why it is there in the example, but most likely it is an error.

Note: The use of `calc()` with single values as described by [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47888426/3215948) is a hack. It can be useful in some cases, but it is not the original intention of `calc()`.

Comment: Hm, I always thought a [value was an expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)), too?

Comment: Reading Wikipedia and the Microsoft docs, I get a different impression. This got me curious enough to actually [ask this as a question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888846/is-a-single-constant-value-considered-an-expression).

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the docs. A single value alone is not an expression, but there are expressions that only have a single value. Example: In this expression `var x = 5;`, the value `5` itself is not an expression, but `x = 5` is. Similarly, if we take the example in this question, the value `40px` is not an expression, but `calc(40px)` is. Also `left: 40px` can be considered an expression since it is like saying `left = 40px`.