# CSS `height: calc(100vh);` Vs `height: 100vh;`

Tags: html, css, user-interface, cross-browser

I'm working on a project where the former developer used:

```
.main-sidebar {
    height: calc(100vh);
}
```

I have no way to contact him/her anymore, and I would like to understand what is the difference (if any) between the two methods.

(Is this the right place to ask this question?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unnecessary use of calc() in MDN example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888375/unnecessary-use-of-calc-in-mdn-example) (this isn't an MDN example but it features the same use of calc() with only one value)

Comment: "(Is this the right place to ask this question?)" Yes, don't worry.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no difference, since any time the expression `calc(100vh)` is calculated, it always ends up being `100vh`.

Answer (score 62):

**VH**
`height: 100vh;` means the height of this element is equal to 100% of the viewport height.

example:
`height: 50vh;`
If your screen height is 1000px, your element height will be equal to 500px (50% of 1000px).

**CALC**
`height: calc(100% - 100px);` will calculate the size of the element by using the value of the element.

example:
`height: calc(100% - 100px);`
If your screen height is 1000px, your element height will be equal to 900px (100% of 1000px and minus 100px).

*I think your former developer didn't need to use `calc()` if he/she didn't want to calculate value.

Answer (score 10):

`calc()` is just used to calculate the value inside the parenthesis.

Example height: `calc(100vh - 60px);`

Here the height will be lesser by 60px in viewport height.

Note: Remember to use space before the operator and after the operator if its not working.

Answer (score 7):

The calc() CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values

you may want to refer this 
[Path](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_func_calc)

(The reason former developer used this may be that he's conventionally using it everywhere and it'd be easier to add calculations afterwards)

Comment: I bet the original value was something like calc(100vh - 60px), then later removed -60px

Comment: I totally agree, Russell. Most probably that should have been the case! :p

Comment: 1+ for providing a link to an example that makes things very clear.

Answer (score 4):

A common use case is that at first he substracted the header or any other element.
calc(100vh - 80px).

Comment: So are you saying this was a case of negligence removing the "- 80px" but not the entire calc() expression?

Comment: I concur with @"Dragomir Dan"

Answer (score 3):

Basically calc() function allows mathematical expressions with addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), and division (/) to be used as component values.

Now in your case, both are same as you have not used any calculation. So you can use height: 100vh